# Google maps API without the map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to build an app with simple gui that include: "Start Point" and "End Point". The purpose of the app is to out to the screen how many meters/kilometers the rout that google maps choose, without to present the map itself. How can I do that? All what I found it's with map graphics.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro):

> The Distance Matrix API is a service that provides travel distance and
>   time for a matrix of origins and destinations. The API returns
>   information based on the recommended route between start and end
>   points, as calculated by the Google Maps API, and consists of rows
>   containing duration and distance values for each pair.

In that case you need [`HttpUrlConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection) or something like that for send URL request like:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Washington,DC&destinations=New+York+City,NY&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

and parse JSON (or XML) response like that:

```
{
"destination_addresses" : [ "New York, NY, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Washington, DC, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "225 mi",
                  "value" : 361715
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 hours 49 mins",
                  "value" : 13725
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

**NB!** don't forget to [get API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/get-api-key).

Also take a look at [Official](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start) and other e.g. like [that](https://developer.rackspace.com/blog/introduction-to-the-google-distance-matrix-api/) tutorials and examples.

Comment: Also NB, the OP will need to display attribution if they don't show a map. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/policies#powered